# Formal definition of undefined for a function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm trying to learn set notation. Say you have a partial function $f : A \rightarrow B.$ Would the correct way to say f is undefined at some points in the domain be:

Let $x \in A.$ We say $f(x)$ is undefined if $\nexists c \in B$ such that $f(x)=c.$

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: A point where the function is not defined is by definition out of the domain.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Akash said it was a partial function, not a function.